# Stuck on Rudin's Statement on the Zeros of Cosine Function

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

For cosine and sine function defined as
[image]

How do we derive the last inequality of (50)
[image]

from (48)
[image]

and (47)
[image]
?

Comment: Triangle inequality $|C(x)|\le \frac{|E(ix)|+|E(-ix)|}{2}\le 1$ is sufficient. ($\implies C(x)-C(y)\le 1+1=2$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From (47) and (48), if $x$ is real,
$$
C(x)^2 + S(x)^2 = 1,
$$
therefore
$$
\left\lvert{C(x)}\right\rvert \leqslant 1,
$$
i.e.
$$
-1 \leqslant C(x) \leqslant 1.
$$
Similarly, if $y$ is real,
$$
-1 \leqslant C(y) \leqslant 1.
$$
Therefore, if $x$ and $y$ are real,
$$
-2 \leqslant C(x) - C(y) \leqslant 2.
$$